# python correct dictionary notation

Tags: python, dictionary

I would need something like

```
{"a"=1,"b"=2,"c"=3,"d"=4}
```

but python is not able to decode it, it gives me an error message. is there a way around that?

thank you

Comment: That is not valid json.

Comment: ok, that's exactly what I wanted to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the "=" with ":" should work...

Comment: `>>> import json

>>> print json.loads({"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4})

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#20>", line 1, in <module>
    print json.loads({"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4})
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: it does not work, but that works: `[{"a":1},{"b":2},{"c":3}]`